# register more than one console command in the same file

Tags: symfony, symfony-console

Creating a console command needs to create a PHP file, suffixed with Command.php.
For example, I want to create DocumentCommand.php.

Here comes the difficulty. I would like to insert here 3 commands, such as:

```
document:unused:check
document:unused:delete
document:used:size
```

What is the best way to **do it in a single file** (DocumentCommand.php) if its possible?

Regards, R.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like:

```
class TestCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    private $progress;

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('acme:test')
            ->setDescription('Write your description here.')
            ->addArgument(
                'argument1',
                InputArgument::REQUIRED,
                'Which will be your first argument?'
            )->addArgument(
                'argument2',
                InputArgument::REQUIRED,
                'Which will be your second argument?'
            )
            ->addOption(
                'extra-option',
                null,
                InputOption::VALUE_NONE,
                'Whether or not to do something optional'
            )
        ;
    }
     protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {

        $argument1 = $input->getArgument('argument1');
        $argument2 = $input->getArgument('argument2');

        $extraOption = $input->getArgument('extra-option');

        $output->writeln("Argument 1 is $argument1 , argument is $argument2");
        $output->writeln(PHP_EOL);


        if ($extraOption != null)
        {
            $output->writeln("Extra option is selected");
            $output->writeln(PHP_EOL);
        }
        if($argument1 == 'unused' && $argument2 == 'check')
        {
            /*
            * Do your stuff
            */
        }
        /**
        * Do something here acording to the arguments passed 
        */

        return;
    }
}
```

With this, you can run in terminal (From your project directory):

```
php app/console acme:test unused check --extra-option
```

You can add more required or optional arguments according to your needs and do something when the unused check/delete are detected according to your logic.

> Edit: (using alias)

```
class TestCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
private $progress;

protected function configure()
{
    $this
        ->setName('document:command')
        ->setDescription('Write your description here.')
        ->addArgument(
            'action',
            InputArgument::REQUIRED,
            'Which will be your first argument? (check/delete/size)'
        )
        ->addOption(
            'extra-option',
            null,
            InputOption::VALUE_NONE,
            'Whether or not to do something optional'
        )
        ->setAliases(array('document:unused', 'document:used'))
                ;
}
 protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{

    $action = $input->getArgument('action');

    $commandSelected = $input->getFirstArgument();

    $extraOption = $input->getArgument('extra-option');

    if ($commandSelected == 'document:unused')
    {
        /*
        * Do something
        */
    }
    else if ($commandSelected == 'document:used')
    {
        /*
        * Do something
        */
    }


    if ($extraOption != null)
    {
        $output->writeln("Extra option is selected");
        $output->writeln(PHP_EOL);
    }
    if($action== 'check')
    {
        /*
        * Do your stuff
        */
    }
    else if($action == 'delete')
    {
        /*
        * Do your stuff
        */
    }
    else if($action == 'size')
    {
        /*
        * Do your stuff
        */
    }

    /**
    * Do something here acording to the arguments passed 
    */

    return;
}
}
```

Comment: This is about only one command "acme:test" :) My question is about how to embed more than one command in a single file.

Comment: Well, take a look at this file: "Symfony\Component\Console\Command" As seen there, "acme:test" is only the name property of the command. What you can do is write some aliases to the command, like "acme:test:alias1" and do something according to the selected alias.. It would be one way to achieve what you want to do in only one file :) See the edit I made

Comment: I really appriciate your tries, but it is not I wanted. Beside, I did some research, and had to realitze, there is no way to put more than one command in a single XYZCommand.php file. Have to accept, its need to create a new one for every eachen command :(

Anyway, I really thanks for your effort,